# When to call Android bug reporting tool

Tags: android, debugging

I am trying to use the bug reporting tool of android (the one you can use via power tool shortcut). When should I take the bug report? I have a service crashing and it's reproducible. Should I get the bug report before it happens (which means the tool collects data starting from that point and stops collecting when an error happens) or immediately after the service crashes (which means the error logs are hold in some cache or something like that and the tool gets the last report).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the tool after the crash happens. What it does is read out the logs, so the error must have occurred already, otherwise it won't be there.